# List Item-level permissions now showing Display form

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, permissions, list-item

I have a list with many items and am trying to break inheritance on each item so that a user can only see what they have permission to. I broke inheritance on an item and assigned a user Full Control. However, when she clicks on the item, the display form now states that she doesn't have access to the page.

Comment: Disabling “Limited-access user permission lockdown mode” feature should solve this issue. If not, please provide the detailed error message so that we can troubleshoot for you.

Answer (score 0):

This might happen when "**Limited-access user permission lockdown mode**" feature is activated in the site collection. In my case, it worked when I turned that feature off.

For more information, you can read at [MS Article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/sharing-and-permissions/cannot-access-shared-folder)